# RTF Template Common Header/Footer

Tags: enterprise-architect

By working with multiple user templates in the project, I created a `master document` to aggregate some `model document` with the wanted packages inside (requirements, use cases, etc).

During some common changes to the templates, I find it very frustrating to edit header and footer one by one template file.

Is there not a way to define a header/footer stylesheet to apply to all or certain user templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define header and footer in either the cover page template, or the table of contents template.

This header/footer will then be used by all subsequent templates.

The only caveat is that all subsequent templates will override the header/footer if they define one for themselves, even if the header/footer is empty.

And since there is no way to get rid of a header, in a template, you'll have to create a new template and copy the contents of the original template into the new template.

Comment: I tried to create and apply a Cover Page and then a Table of Content (only cover, then only ToC and then both) template and it didn't work. Are you sure this is the right way? Thanks

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I've done it like that dozens of times. Try it with completely new templates to be sure. Make a Cover page template with header/footer and a new template where you don't even touch the header/footer option. That should work.

Comment: Yes, you were right! My RTF template are corrupted or messed up in the header. Now I create new template copying only the content and the master document apply the main header and footer. Great! Thanks a lot!